# What happens if two win conditions are fulfilled on the same turn in Civ VI?

Tags: civilization-6

I understand that you can only win once in Civ VI, but what happens if for example the culture and religion win conditions are fulfilled on the start of the same turn? Are they ranked? Which cinematic scene is shown and how does the game decide between them?

Comment: I'd be impressed if you could line it up - I can't answer for certain, but I know culture/religion is calculated between turns, science/score completes on the start of your turn, domination is instant during your turn.

Comment: @n_plum Yeah, I don’t think I’d be able in practice. :-) But it is interesting. Almost could be a new challenge like speedrunning.

Answer (score 1):

It's a race condition - meaning whichever condition the software would calculate first would "win". The order is not always the same  and for some things Civ 6 alternates the order of evaluation.

If you'd really, really want to test you'd need a giant contrivance setup and then to click [one more turn] to see if it's going to trip and check the other condition. That would be a bug since once a victory is set there's a fuze (flag) that normally prevents evaluation of victory conditions ever again.